Infinitely looped Instagram random selector filter in Spark AR
I'm trying to create a random selector filter for Instagram. It does work as I wanted, i.e. randomly selecting an image after a screen tap, but it works only once after you reset the filter. I want it to be looped, so that after it selects a picture you can tap the screen again and select another one an infinite amount of times. You can see my patch editor on the screen:

I tried connecting "Reset" from Loop Animation back to Screen Tap but it doesn't work. Couldn't find any other way to make it work
